Convert WordPress into Event and membership managment software
My Brother asked me if I can make for him a club and event software that mange his Athlete instead of doing it manually with google forms and spreadsheets.
I am not developer. I have very basic knowledge in PHP and CSS. so I looked around for something already built up that can do what he looking for but no luck.
I wonder if I can convert WordPress to be a management system for membership and events. I will share my thoughts for what I need exactly. which i consider the basic tools my brother need for this system

Make registration form with custom field and the Custom field unlock based on specific conditions
Users register based on roles coaches, athlete, referee etc... and what club this user belong to
After Registration users should get unique id like ID-#####. users can login with this id as alternative to email login
Any Registrations should be pending before approval by admin.
After approval. when the users login will auto redirect to dashboard page
The Event page showing as grid view for example:- Event Page
Athlete can view events and see who participate to this event. example:- Event details
Athlete cannot join the events by themselves . ONLY coaches can join the event with the Athlete as a team, examples:-
Event participation example 1
Event Participation example 2
Coaches have ability to make teams and add Athlete to it ONLY if the Athlete register under same club as the coach register (Cant add or view other coaches or Athlete from different club) for example:-
Add new team
Manage teams

with my very basic knowledge is it achievable to make it with plugins available and some lines of codes? or this require a very deep coding?
If it possible what plugins you guys recommend to achieves one of those requirements above?
Regards

Plugin recomendations are off topic for this Stack, as they tend to attract subjective answers.

@ChrisCox Ok. how about the idea i shared in general with plugins use (in general) would be possible to make this kind of system in WordPress or it will have problems?

you can develop what you want with the wordpress framework but you need knowledges in data structure and in php.

Lord Matt gave a great reply, I would only echo how important it is to setup a dev, sandbox, whatever for testing...there are a number of plugins that will help you achieve what you want, but some don't do a good job of cleaning up after themselves if you decide to use a different one, leaving detritus in your DB...using a sandbox will help you identify the plugins you'll want to use, which you can then add to a clean install of WP.  Same goes for Themes, some override basic functionality, then don't revert that functionality when you change Themes, so testing is vital.

I have actually built a system that does all of this, with WordPress, using a custom theme & a custom plugin.  I built one previously that was for youth athletes & incorporated evaluations & ecommerce more so than team & league management.  You can see the front end at https://bramptonsoccer.com
The truth is, it wasn't easy.  I spent 2 years of my spare time, when the league was shut down for the pandemic, writing the code for that site & at least once a month I'll dedicate a weekend to improve functions or add new features, like SMS messaging.

That can be done, yes. It is a fairly common use of WordPress. I've seen many plugins that help you do just that. As plugin recommendations are off-topic, I'll leave choosing to you.
What I will do is outline a good approach to working on such a project.
Step one - know exactly what you need
Before you start installing stuff, make a detailed list of the features you want now and may want further down the line. Talk to your brother about this because changing plugin later will be a massive hassle.
Devide the list into must have, would be good to have, and nice but can live without.
Talk about budget with him. Many plugins have paid version with more features. This may or may not be right for your project.
Step two - figure out what is available.
The fewer plugins you need to do this the better time you are likely to have getting them all to work together. Good custom theme work can cover a lot of cracks here.
Identify you options and grade them on how well they meet the needs you listed. Reject anything that does not cover the must haves (that another plugin cannot fill in for).
I'd combine googleing for lists of "best X for Y" type posts with searching the WordPress repository.
You should now have a short list of the things that best meet your needs. If not, you may need to hire someone to write something for you. Comisioning something custom is going to hurt your budget so be aware of that going in.
Step three - try some stuff out
In whatever way you can, spin up a dev, local, test, whatever copy of WordPress and try out some of your best ranked options. This will show you any gotchas, headaches, or poorly working plugins.
Illiminate any options that are too much fuss, don't work, and/or have poor support. You are looking for a set up that is within budget, is workable at your skill level, and has good support when things go wrong (and they will).
Step four - customise as needed
Now you have a favourite (hopefully) it is time to pair that with a good theme (repeated the first three steps for the theme too - you want something that will work well with your plugins and that looks the part).
Step five - roll it out
Now you are ready to hit the go button.
If what you have is not working, reload early. Its much less painful to reboot with new choices when you only have a small user base.
The best teacher is just giving it a go. In the worse case, you will have leaned something for next time.

Kudos, Lord Matt for a thoughtful and helpful response!
